# Is it possible to ask for updates on a question or how the user dealt with the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

There are some questions without answers for a while (at least one year old). Is there a way to ask the user for updates or if he/she found an answer to his/her question?

I do not want to ask the same question to avoid [duplicate].

Note: take in consideration that I cannot comment.

Comment: Note: It's quite easy to get 5 more reputation points to enable you for commenting.

Comment: You can: edit the question to improve it, leave a comment, and/or start a bounty. The latter two require more reputation than you currently have, so your only real option is editing. The comment privilege is easily achievable for you, but that won't really do any good. An "any updates?" comment is just noise.

Comment: Note that "edit the question to improve it" does *not* mean "edit your additional questions and/or comments into the question".